# is_page conditional question

Tags: conditional-tags

I am using `is_page` in my `functions.php` file to display some code and I wanted only to display the code in the header if the contact page is being shown. I made a template called contact.php and in the top did the template name: contact. The templates shows just fine but when I went into the functions file and did `is_page('contact')` or `is_page('contact.php')` the code stopped working. Is the function based on the permalinks settings? right now I have wordpress setup for default so instead of showing `contact.php` in the address bar, it shows ?`page_id=94`. If I do `is_page(94)` then my test code works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the page slug is 'contact' then is_page('contact') should work. You can check out the optional parameters for page in the codex [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page#Examples) . Using post ID, e.g. 94 in your example will work regardless of permalink settings.

If you want it to display for a specific template you can use is_page_template('contact.php').

Comment: OH, that makes sense. Thaks for the tips.